# Check if two checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where a user needs to click two checkboxes before continuing (agree to two terms of service). My jQuery is fairly straightforward, you have to have both check boxes checked to continue:

```
$("#agree1, #agree2").click(function () {
    if ($("#agree1").is(':checked') == true && $("#agree2").is(':checked') == true) {
        $("#nextPage").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $("#nextPage").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

I'm wondering if there is a simpler way of writing this. I expected a line like this to check for both boxes to be checked, but it doesn't:

```
if ($("#agree1 #agree2").is(':checked') == true)
```

Is there a way to simplify this?

Example code: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LWd7Z/1/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can look for only the checked checkboxes, and then check that you found two:

```
if ($("#agree1:checked,#agree2:checked").length == 2) { ... }
```